# Finding the cause of a 3930 SQL Server error

Tags: sql-server, debugging, error-handling

I have a script I wrote which is giving me a 3930 error on a particular line. It's a simple update statement and it fails when I run it in the script but if I print the variables from the script and run it manually the line executes fine. Does anybody know how I can track this error down?

The line is executed in a cursor and runs hundreds of times correctly previous to this loop. I get the error if I let it process all the records or update my cursor query to select only this one.

The full error message is:

> *Msg 3930, Level 16, State 1, Line 160
>
>   The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.*

The offending line is:

```
UPDATE [DBName].[dbo].[TableName] 
SET [XXX] = @XXX, [DateEdited] = GETDATE(), [EditedBy] = 'MyUser' 
WHERE [YYY] = @YYY
```

EDIT:

I sanitised the query so that I could post it here; see it below. A couple things to note.

1) For Contractor "ABCDEF" there is only one record in [FactoryDB].[dbo].[AuditInformation] so cursor B is not necessary for this record. I tried removing the cursor and leaving all of the contained code but that fixed the error

2) Removing the try-catch block that parses the age fixes the error as well even though it's not used by any of the remaining code. FYI that code does error and the catch block executes.

```
--TABLE TO HOLD ERROR MESSAGES
declare @errors TABLE (FormId int, FactoryContractorCode nvarchar(50), FactoryId nvarchar(50), ErrorMessage nvarchar(1000) )

--DECLARE VARIABLES
DECLARE @factoryCode nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @factoryId nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @formId int
DECLARE @auditDate DateTime
DECLARE @totalEmployees int
DECLARE @ageRange nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @ageAverage int
DECLARE @percentageFemale int
DECLARE @percentageMale int
DECLARE @rowIdToUpdate nvarchar(50)

DECLARE @tempFormId int
DECLARE @tempDateString nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @tempAuditDate DateTime

--CURSOR TO LOOP THROUGH ALL FACTORY CODES
DECLARE a CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT [FactoryCode] FROM [FactoryDB].[dbo].[AuditInformation] WHERE [FactoryCode] = 'ABCDEF'
OPEN a
FETCH a into @factoryCode
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    --RESET VARIABLES TO NULL
    SET @totalEmployees = NULL
    SET @ageRange = NULL
    SET @formId = NULL
    SET @rowIdToUpdate = NULL
    SET @tempAuditDate = NULL
    SET @auditDate = NULL
    SET @ageAverage = NULL
    SET @percentageFemale = NULL
    SET @percentageMale = NULL
    SET @tempFormId = NULL
    SET @tempDateString = NULL
    SET @factoryId = NULL

    SELECT @factoryId=[ContractorID] FROM [DataDB].[dbo].[ContractorIdentifier] WHERE [ContractorCode] = @factoryCode

    --FIND THE FORM ID WITH THE MOST RECENT DATE
    DECLARE b CURSOR FOR
        SELECT [FormId],[StartDate] FROM [FactoryDB].[dbo].[AuditInformation] WHERE [FactoryCode] = @factoryCode AND NOT [StartDate] IS NULL
    OPEN b
    FETCH b into @tempFormId, @tempDateString
    WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        --PARSE THE FORM DATE
        BEGIN TRY
            SET @tempAuditDate = CAST(@tempDateString AS DateTime)
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            INSERT INTO @errors ([FormId],[FactoryContractorCode],[FactoryId],[ErrorMessage]) VALUES (@tempFormId, @factoryCode, @factoryId, 'Unable to parse date value of: '''+@tempDateString+'''')
        END CATCH

        --FIRST TIME
        IF (@auditDate IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @auditDate = @tempAuditDate
            SET @formId = @tempFormId
        END

        --UPDATE IF THE NEW DATE IS MORE RECENT THAN THE PREVIOUS ONE
        IF(@tempAuditDate > @auditDate)
        BEGIN
            SET @auditDate = @tempAuditDate
            SET @formId = @tempFormId
        END

    FETCH b into @tempFormId, @tempDateString
    END
    CLOSE b
    DEALLOCATE b

    --IF A FORM WAS FOUND WITH A PARSABLE DATE
    IF (NOT @formId IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        --GET AUDIT INFORMATION
        SELECT TOP 1
            @totalEmployees = m.[TotarEmployees]
            ,@ageRange = m.[EmployeeAgeRange]
        FROM [FactoryDB].[dbo].[AuditInformation] g
        INNER JOIN [FactoryDB].[dbo].[AuditData] m on g._form_id = m._form_id
        WHERE g.[_form_id] = @formId

        --PARSE THE AVERAGE AGE FROM THE VARCHAR COLUMN
        BEGIN TRY
            DECLARE @low int
            DECLARE @high int

            SET @low = CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@ageRange,0,CHARINDEX('-',@ageRange)))) AS int)
            SET @high = CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@ageRange,CHARINDEX('-',@ageRange)+1,LEN(@ageRange)))) AS int)
            SET @ageAverage = ROUND((@low+@high)/2, 0)
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            INSERT INTO @errors ([FormId],[FactoryContractorCode],[FactoryId],[ErrorMessage]) VALUES (@formId, @factoryCode, @factoryId, 'Unable to parse age value of: '''+@ageRange+'''')
        END CATCH
    END


    --UPDATE THE FACTORY VIEW TABLE
    SELECT TOP 1 @rowIdToUpdate = [Id] FROM [DataDB].[dbo].[DataTable] WHERE [ContractorID] = @factoryId  AND [DateEdited] < @auditDate ORDER BY [DateEdited] DESC

    IF (NOT @rowIdToUpdate IS NULL)
    BEGIN

        IF(NOT @totalEmployees IS NULL)
            UPDATE [DataDB].[dbo].[EmployeeStats] SET  [TotalEmployees] = @totalEmployees, [DateEdited] = GETDATE(), [EditedBy] = 'LstAD' WHERE [RowIDs] = @rowIdToUpdate
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO @errors ([FormId],[FactoryContractorCode],[FactoryId],[ErrorMessage]) VALUES (@formId, @factoryCode, @factoryId, 'Did not update Total Employees. Value was null or unable to be calculated.')
    END

ROLLBACK
FETCH a into @factoryCode
END
CLOSE a
DEALLOCATE a

--DO SOMETHING WITH THE ERRORS TABLE VARIABLE
SELECT * FROM @errors
```

Comment: Any update trigger on that table?

Comment: If there isn't a trigger on the table, you'll need to show more code. Cursor declaration and transaction statements could be quite relevant, but the more details we have, the better we can help you. Right now we don't have enough details to guess.

Comment: Usually, this error is preceded by another error that puts the transaction into an uncommitable state.

Comment: I sanitized the query and removed as much extraneous code as possible so I could post it. Hopefully that helps. Also I checked the table and didn't see any triggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that even if it's inside a Try/Catch block an error will prevent the transaction from being committed. I was unaware of this. I re-wrote the "--PARSE THE AVERAGE AGE FROM THE VARCHAR COLUMN" code to use ISNUMERIC as a check before trying to do the math and that fixed the issue. Thanks for the help commenters. I wouldn't have figured it out otherwise.